"update or delete on table \"category\" violates foreign key constraint \"product_category_id_fkey\" on table \"product\""
I'm using postgresql and sequelize in javascript. I continue to get this error when trying to delete an item from the category table. It occurred suddenly without any changes to the route or associations between tables. It occurs both in postman and insomnia, but oddly not my terminal. I have tried rebooting everything.
My models:
Category.init(
  {
    // define columns
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    category_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    }
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true,
    underscored: true,
    modelName: 'category',
  }
);

Product.init(
  {
    // define columns
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    product_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    price: {
      type: DataTypes.DECIMAL,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        isDecimal: true
      }
    },
    stock: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 10,
      validate: {
        isNumeric: true
      }
    },
    category_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: 'category',
        key: 'id'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true,
    underscored: true,
    modelName: 'product',
  }
);

My associations:
// Products belongsTo Category
Product.belongsTo(Category, {
  foreignKey: 'category_id'
})

// Categories have many Products
Category.hasMany(Product, {
  foreignKey: 'category_id',
  onDelete: 'CASCADE'
})

My delete route:
router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
  // delete a category by its `id` value
  Category 
    .destroy({where: { id: req.params.id}})
    .then(response => {
      res.json({status: 'success', payload: response})
    })
    .catch( err => res.status(500).json({status: 'error', payload: err.message}))
});

I apologize if this is a simple oversight. I'm just learning.

Make sure that your data modifications don't violate the integrity constraints of the database.

Did you check that you have this option ONDELETE: CASCADE in the FK in DB?

You try to delete data that is still in use by other records. Delete these records first, change your foreign key to cascade the delete to these records or don't delete this record at all. It depends on your business and data logic what's the best solution.
